# How to change DateTime field value on form submit

Tags: 8, datetime

I am trying to update a DateTime field in an altered form submit. Something like:

```
function my_module_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if (!$profile->field_someother_field->isEmpty()) {
    $date = new DrupalDateTime();
    $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone(DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE));
    $string = $date->format(DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
    $form_state->setValue('field_date_updated_details', [$string]);
  }
}
```

But this fails with various messages (depending on whether I set the value as an array or directly as string).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The form value need to be an call DrupalDateTime, so you can directly pass **$date** as value.

Comment: I tried that as well and it still throws an exception :/

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar problem, and the following kind of thing works for me:

```
$form_state->setValue('field_date_updated_details', [['value' => $date]]);
```

As another respondent noted, I'm not using a string, but the actual DrupalDateTime object, and setting the **'value'** inside that nested array.